# How to use Rspec any_instance_of if you don't know all the WITH values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I am creating a new record in my tests... during the creation of the record, the application calls another class to notify a user about the creation of the record..

A contrived example might be

```
 user = User.make!
 expect_any_instance_of(Notifier).to receive(:tell_user).with(user.id, new_message_id)
 Message.create(author: User.make!, recepient: user, message: 'this is a test')
```

Now obviously I don't know the id of the message that will be created.
So I'm wondering if anyone knows how I'd construct the with part of the expect to not care about the value in the second parameter, but to care about the value in the first parameter.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `kind_of` method

```
user = User.make!
expect_any_instance_of(Notifier).to receive(:tell_user).with(user.id, kind_of(Numeric))
Message.create(author: User.make!, recepient: user, message: 'this is a test')
```

You can also use `instance_of(Fixnum)` if you want to be more specific